# Script for extracting the first member of each tuple in a line of tuples

Tags: bash, shell, tuples, cut, csh

I have a file where each line is a list of tuples the following format:

```
[('a1','b1','c1','d1','e1'), ('a2','b2','c2','d2','e2'), ..., ('an','bn','cn','dn','en')]
```

n, meaning the list length could be different for each line.

My goal is to extract the first member of each tuple, meaning, I want the following output for each line:

```
a1 a2 ... an
```

I would know how to do this if the number of tuples was known, but I can't generalize.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/[^(]*\('([^']+)'[^(]*/\1 /g; s/ $//" < tuples.txt
```

Which will produce:

```
a1 a2 an
```